# Google Sheets- SUMIFS Using Partial Date from Time Stamp

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, sumifs

I am trying to setup a sheet to use the SUMIFS formula to look for a partial date within a timestamp which then sums a range based on that match.

The initial data is being input from a Google Form, which only provides timestamps rather than short dates (MM/DD/YYYY) - This means when I'm trying to calculate 'Today's Sales' there are no matches due to my formula looking for the short date.

The formula I'm currently using is:

=SUMIFS('Form Responses 1'!D:D,'Form Responses 1'!$A:$A,$A$1,'Form Responses 1'!$G:$G,A3)

With cell A1 being a reference date that needs to remain changeable (i.e, enter any date needed)

If I change the data in Column A of the 'Form Responses 1' sheet to short dates I can get matches for what i'm looking for, but as this information comes from a google form I cannot manually change it each time I need to search.

So what I'm hoping for is a formula similar to the one above, but instead can use cell A1 as a reference date and find matches for short dates from Column A's timestamps on the 'Form Responses 1' sheet.

I hope I explained that correctly, but here is an example google sheet of what i'm using:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A64a9A9Jdjru-1dEIn09togGbPYjTMbFfpwtUoVUGKc/edit#gid=0

Comment: Where would the SUMIF formula go? On the sheet shared, there are many different formulas on `Today's Sales` sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it works now! Put a DateValue() arround the dates in A:A and put the entire formula in a Arrayformula in order to work :D
the formula for B3 is `=Arrayformula( SUMIFS('Form Responses 1'!D:D,DATEVALUE( 'Form Responses 1'!$A:$A ),$A$1,'Form Responses 1'!$G:$G,$A3))`
cheers

PS (also i Put an $ in the end (A3 --> $A3) so it can easily change columns)

Comment: Amazing thank you! This works great. I tried following that format to apply to the COUNTIFS formula in cell D3. Does this also work for COUNTIFS? If so could you provide the format to follow to apply the arrayforula with datevalue please?

Comment: Actually please ingore the above, I was able to format it correctly to work on the COUNTIFS too, thanks again apostolos55!